# How to handle events of objects outside of a View in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

As in the backbone-todolist example,I have a collection of elements. I made 2 views, one for the list and one for each element. It works great.

However, as I need the elements of the list to be modified, **in the view of the element** I handle the modify event **opening a popup with the [colorbox plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)** which contains an html form.
The html is dynamically created and passed to the colorbox element.

I use colorbox and backbone-form additional plugins.

Now: the popup IS NOT A CHILD (in the DOM) of my view, so I don't know how to fire the event on the 'button submit' action.

Here is a snippet of the code (omitted unuseful parts):

```
// ** view of the single collection element
window.listElement = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    [...]

    updateElement:function(){
        //creates the update form in a popup menu
        var form=new Backbone.Form({BLA BLA BLA...I TESTED IT, IT WORKS.
            }).render();
        $(form.el).append('<input id="update-btn" type="button" name="updateBtn" value="Update" style="display: block;">');
        self=this;

        //HERE COME THE TROUBLES
        $.colorbox({
            html:form.el,
            [...] /SOME OTHER PARAMS
            }).delegate('#update-btn','click',self.saveEl());
        },
    saveEl:function(){
        console.log("now saving..")},       
        },
```

What happens is that the saveEl method (or function?, which term would be more correct?) is fired when the popup is opened.

I also tried with a different version of the code:

```
    initialize: function(){//added this in the initialize function
        _.bindAll(this, "saveEl");
        $('#update-btn').bind('click', this.saveEl());
          },
    updateElement:function(){
        //LIKE BEFORE BUT WITHOUT DELEGATE FUNCTION
        $.colorbox({
            html:form.el,
            [...] /SOME OTHER PARAMS
            });
        },
        saveEl:function(){
           console.log("now saving..")},        
        },
```

In this second case, the saveEl function is called when the view is created (thus one time for each element of the list).

I know that I colud make a view for the popup, but somEthing says me that it's too complicated and that there should me a more simple architecture.

The question, indeed, is more general: is it possible to handle events fired by DOM object outside the scope of $(this.el) **without creating a view for them**?

thanks in advance.

**-----------------UPDATE:--------------**

The final version of working code is the following:

```
// ** view of the single collection element
window.listElement = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    [...]

    updateElement:function(){
        //creates the update form in a popup menu
        var form=new Backbone.Form({BLA BLA BLA...I TESTED IT, IT WORKS.
            }).render();
        $(form.el).append('<input id="update-btn" type="button" name="updateBtn" value="Update" style="display: block;">');
        $(form.el).delegate('#update-btn','click',this.saveEl())
        $.colorbox({
            html:form.el,
            [...] /SOME OTHER PARAMS
            });
        },
    saveEl:function(){
        console.log("now saving..")},       
        }
     });
```

Comment: first comment after debugging:
changing $('#update-btn').bind('click', this.saveEl());
to $('#update-btn').bind('click', this.saveEl);
(NO PARENTHESIS after this.saveEl) eliminates the problem of calling the function once for each view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

$.colorbox doesn't send back the right html to bind it.

As you can see, you give to colorbox `form.el`, so you can directly bind `form.el`:

```
$(form.el).on('click', '#update-btn', self.saveEl);
// here your colorbox code
$.colorbox({
    html: form.el,
    // [...] SOME OTHER PARAMS
});
```

*You should use `on` now because `delegate` is an old method: http://api.jquery.com/on/*

**----------------------**

Yes, you can handle events fired by DOM object outside the scope of the view, you just need to use `$('#your-element')` instead `this.$('#your-element')`.

For your code, it's normal to trigger `saveEl` directly because you give to `delegate` the result of that function, you need to give the pointer of the function like this:

```
$.colorbox({
    html: form.el,
    // [...] SOME OTHER PARAMS
}).delegate('#update-btn', 'click', self.saveEl); // without ()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm dealing with javascript from some months so I've to refresh many things I learnt programming in different languages (as the pointer and the function).
However, it's still not working. I used delegate as you suggest, but nothing happens and I can't understand why. Maybe that appending it after the colorbox codes is not the best solution?
Also: form your answer I understand that putting $('#update-btn').bind('click', this.saveEl) in the initialize function limitate the scope of the bind within the view. Isn't it?

Comment: It's the opposite, with $('#update-btn').bind('click', this.saveEl) you don't limite your scope. The deleguate method doesn't work because $.colorbox doesn't send back the right element to bind...I will edit my answer to give you the right approach, I just find the solution now.

Comment: thanks again. I tried to put $('#updatebtn').bind('click',this.saveRI);
in the initialize of the view, but it doesn't work: mabye because the $('#updatebtn') element still doesn't exist when binding? 

The only workaround I found at the moment is to extend the Backbone.Form view adding      `events:{"click #updatebtn":"functionToBeTriggered"}` ... it means creating a view (the solution I didn't want to use)... however, I'll wait for your code. Thnak you and goobye. Au revoir :-)

Comment: Dear Atinux, I finally did it!! just adding
`$(form.el).delegate('#updatebtn','click',  this.saveEl);`
after the creation of the form.

Thanks a lot, I could have stuck on this simple problem for a long time without your help.

Comment: With pleasure ! I edited my original post and I explain that you need to use `on` method instead of `delegate` (old method).

Comment: Yes I saw it. Thanks, really explicative and useful.
I used delegate (and not 'on') function as I'm using jquery<1.7
I put in the EDIT  section of my post the the final version of the working code for users who're interested in.
bye.